# message: "Request failed with status code 404", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, response: {…} }

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, express-jwt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaKD0.png)

I have uploaded project on Server. After that message: "Request failed with status code 404", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, response: {…} }

GET https://uat.sibinsure.com/verify  -  404 error

404 error showing in all pages.

Comment: Hi, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 404 is actually when there is no route acceptance. can you check in local or see if it has deployed